# Авторизация на Flask, бд SQLAclhemy - sqlite3

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
@app.route('/signin', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def signin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       login = request.form.get('login')
       password = request.form.get('password')
       # user = users.query.all()  КАК ПОЛУЧИТЬ КОНКРЕТНОГО ЮЗЕРА? 
       # user[0].login == login сравнит только первую запись с бд, а мне 
       # нужно чтобы он все записи сравнивал
    #  if (Условие какое - то):
    #      return 'Все хорошо мы нашли такого'
    #  else:
    #      return 'Не найден'
return render_template('signin.html')
```

Мне надо как то сравнить user получаемый с формы с users из бд. Кодил только на C++ builder-ре, и там достаточно при помощи SELECT * FROM table WHERE login = 'login' AND password = 'password' сравнить. А тут не понял как.

Comment: Убрал скриншот, поставил код

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/signin', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form.get('login')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        
        # Проверка наличия пользователя в базе данных
        user = user.query.filter_by(login=login, password=password).first()
        
        if user:
            return 'Все хорошо, мы нашли такого пользователя'
        else:
            return 'Пользователь не найден'
    
    return render_template('signin.html')
```

хотя тут еще надо учесть, это то что пароли так не надо хранить)